# Deploying Puppeteer-extra with stealth-plugin to Heroku: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: heroku, puppeteer

I try to depoloy my scriper to Heroku. Unfortunatly, to successfully obtain infromation from the target site I need to use **puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth**. For deploying I use https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack and heroku/nodejs buildpacks.

package.json:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.2.1"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.13.0",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.6",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.2",
    "valid-url": "^1.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

I am gettting error in logs like this

```
2023-04-18T08:14:51.826198+00:00 app\[web.1\]: \> headless-chrome@1.0.0 start /app
2023-04-18T08:14:51.826198+00:00 app\[web.1\]: \> node app.js
2023-04-18T08:14:51.826199+00:00 app\[web.1\]:
2023-04-18T08:14:52.263998+00:00 app\[web.1\]: /app/node_modules/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/evasions/chrome.app/index.js:68
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264011+00:00 app\[web.1\]:         ...STATIC_DATA,
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264011+00:00 app\[web.1\]:         ^^^
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264012+00:00 app\[web.1\]:
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264012+00:00 app\[web.1\]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264013+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264013+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264013+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Module.\_compile (module.js:533:28)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264014+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264014+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264014+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264015+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Function.Module.\_load (module.js:458:3)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264015+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264015+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.264016+00:00 app\[web.1\]:     at Object.\<anonymous\> (/app/app.js:7:23)
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274250+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274322+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR! errno 1
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274372+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR! headless-chrome@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274412+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274458+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR!
2023-04-18T08:14:52.274501+00:00 app\[web.1\]: npm ERR! Failed at the headless-chrome@1.0.0 start script.
```

What can I do to fix that problem? In localhost the app is working perfectly with current configurations. I suppose, that Heroku needs some bins or other things to run this plugin, but I don't know how can I provide it.
I tried to deploy app without stealth plugin and code is running without any problems, but access to target site can't be gained. So I suppose that problem is in using **puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth**.